# How can I place a pause in an ASP.NET Web Application during page rendering to wait for a sub containing a SQL query to complete execution?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have an ASP.NET application that works fine on the deployed server, but when I run it from a remote development computer connected to the production database, it displays the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object," which I assume is due to the SQL query used to populate some combo boxes, or perhaps the main sub populating the grid, not returning in time for the entire page to finish rendering.

These are the subs with SQL queries: **FillGridOnLoad()**, **FillAseguradoraDropdownList()** and **FillDoctorDropdownList()**

I'm guessing that introducing a pause in the page rendering to wait for all those subs with SQL queries to complete might solve the problem. Does that make sense? In that case, where is the wait to be inserted?

```
Partial Class all orders
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub gridOrdenes_PageIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gridOrdenes.PageIndexChanged
    gridOrdenes.AllowPaging = True
End Sub

Protected Sub gridOrdenes_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gridOrdenes.PageIndexChanging
    gridOrdenes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    FillGridOnLoad()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

'...some code for authentication, etc... and then the following is the last part of the code:

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillGridOnLoad()

        'Se llena el dropdown de laboratorios
        Dim laboratorios As New laboratorios

        dropLaboratorio.DataSource = laboratorios.fetch_all()
        dropLaboratorio.DataTextField = "laboratorio"
        dropLaboratorio.DataValueField = "idLaboratorio"
        dropLaboratorio.DataBind()
        dropLaboratorio.Items.Insert(0, "")

        FillAseguradoraDropdownList()
        FillDoctorDropdownList()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: find what method is producing the error, run one method at a time and see which ones complain.

Comment: Don't assume. That's what the stack is for. Please post the whole exception stack so we can help you identify which `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: How would adding a pause of say 10 seconds help? All that would do is have the code wait for the query (maybe 5 seconds), and then you wait 10 seconds more - all that is going to do is hold up the page on the server for 15 seconds total time. if that query is timing out, then that query is timing out. You have to increase the timeout of the connection string from what I can tell here. But, if a data pull is timing out, then you either catch that error, or you deal with increasing the timeout for that query.

Comment: Full stacktrace when you have an exception. You have something that is failing to be created. My guess is your grid itself isn't created before you try to either 1 populate it or 2 databind it. Also, inclue ALL code that may be relevant unless you know for certain it has not and you have testing it in isolation. Debugging your code properly with breakpoints should solve this.

Comment: Strangely enough, the same code deployed  to the live server is not showing the error, I mean when the calling code resides in the same server as the MySQL Server it's getting the data from, as opposed when running it on a remote dev machine connecting to the deployed Database.

Comment: Maybe I need to study VB Tasks